# Without Quorum Drive.. will it work node1 and node2 in cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

Without Quorum Drive.. will it work node1 and node2 in cluster. How it is possible? if not required then where it stores cluster information?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question isn't quite a question let me answer it as best I can.

> Without Quorum Drive.. will it work node1 and node2 in cluster.

That depends. How any nodes are in the cluster? What are the node weights? What version of Windows is it?

> How it is possible?

Each node has a copy of the cluster database.

> if not required then where it stores cluster information?

In the registry under the Cluster keys.